# Drag and Drop a folder

Tags: vb.net

I have an application that what simple it made is drag and drop a file from my computer to the application and then it displays the name, the type, the size, when was created, modified and last access. But I realized that it only drop files and I want it to drop folders too.

This is the layout of the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pyLx.png)

And after I drop a file(could be a shortcut, .exe, excel file, .rar, ...)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JI0i.png)

If I try to drop a folder, I can do this, but doesn't show anything and I can't understand why.

Here's the DragEnter and DragDrop code respectively

DragEnter

```
If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
```

DragDrop

```
Dim file As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)

    MyFile = New FileInfo(file)

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyFile.Extension) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ShowInfoFiles()

    UpdateControls()
```

After some tests I found that this might be the main problem. The code below is what will update after drop the file on that labels inside of a private sub ShowInfoFiles().

```
    lblName.Text = MeuFicheiro.Name
    lblType.Text = MeuFicheiro.Extension
    lblSize.Text = Math.Round(MeuFicheiro.Length / 1024) & "KB"
    pbIcon.Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(MeuFicheiro.FullName).ToBitmap
```

And if I comment change this line of code

If you could help me solve or try to solve this problem I would appreciate it.

```
MyFile.Extension
```

to

```
MyFile.Name
```

it will just show me the name on debug. So I presume that it could be related to Extension and Icon

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a directory exists with the name of the dropped entity:

```
Dim item As String = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), Array).GetValue(0).ToString
If Directory.Exists(item) Then
    ' process item as a directory
Else
    ' process item as a file
End If
```

[It looks like you might not be using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). I strongly recommend that you do.]

Comment: But I will use that condition on DragDrop or DragEnter?

Comment: You would use it in the DragDrop handler. Also, you will have to write different code when a directory is dropped, e.g. you might want to show the quantity of files in the directory and the sum of their sizes.

Comment: I already solve my problem. I was thinking about that and the possibility to drop a folder isn't a problem because I don't need. Thank you for your help